# Get current name in protractor multicapabilities config?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using browser.getCapabilities() to get browserName and platform details.

Multicapabilities config:

```
    multiCapabilities:[
    {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    name: 'iPhone',
    chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--window-size=400,800','--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A4449d Safari/9537.53"']
        }
    }
    ]
```

"browser.getCapabilities()" returns the below,

```
    { caps_: 
       { platform: 'MAC',
         acceptSslCerts: true,
         javascriptEnabled: true,
         browserName: 'chrome',
         chrome: { userDataDir: '/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.ten2tT' },
         rotatable: false,
         locationContextEnabled: true,
         mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
         'webdriver.remote.sessionid': '1a7542e9-8a70-469c-964d-3c3cd4330145',
         version: '40.0.2214.93',
         takesHeapSnapshot: true,
         cssSelectorsEnabled: true,
         databaseEnabled: false,
         handlesAlerts: true,
         browserConnectionEnabled: false,
         nativeEvents: true,
         webStorageEnabled: true,
         applicationCacheEnabled: false,
         takesScreenshot: true } }
```

Is there any way to get the name from the capability object?

Comment: what "name" are you referring to?

Comment: He's referring to the 'name' attribute of the multiCapabilities object that's running the current browser, eg 'iPhone'. Would be highly useful to me too, but it seems only defined attributes are passed over to getCapabilities().

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple browsers setup in the conf.js page the following should return the browser name that the test is running in:

`browser.browserName`

In the beforeEach function for a test I added `console.log(browser.browserName);` and it exported the correct Browser Name for each of the tests.

```
[launcher] Running 3 instances of WebDriver

------------------------------------
[safari #2] PID: 36412
[safari #2] Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[safari #2] safari
[safari #2] 
[safari #2]   Test - pass
[safari #2] 
[safari #2] 
[safari #2] Finished in 1.469 seconds
[safari #2] 1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
[safari #2] 

[launcher] 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running

------------------------------------
[firefox #3] PID: 36413
[firefox #3] Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[firefox #3] firefox
[firefox #3] 
[firefox #3]   Test - pass
[firefox #3] 
[firefox #3] 
[firefox #3] Finished in 1.464 seconds
[firefox #3] 1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
[firefox #3] 

[launcher] 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running

------------------------------------
[chrome #1] PID: 36411
[chrome #1] Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[chrome #1] chrome
[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1]   Test - pass
[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1] 
[chrome #1] Finished in 2.173 seconds
[chrome #1] 1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
[chrome #1] 

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] safari #2 passed
[launcher] firefox #3 passed
[launcher] chrome #1 passed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This seems not to work in the current (=3.0.0) version of protractor :(

Comment: I think this will work for 3.0 and up

    browser.getCapabilities().then(function(cap) {
      browser.browserName = cap.get('browserName');
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional information inside the `onPrepare` method, like:

```
browser.getCapabilities()
  .then( cap => browser.name = cap.caps_.browserName )
```

where `browserName` is a property of the `multiCapabilities` object:

```
chrome: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  logName: 'Chrome'
},
firefox: {
  browserName: 'firefox',
  logName: 'Firefox'
}
```

Inside your tests you can then use `browser.name` to retrieve the name of the current browser.

**Update 2017-01-07:**

For Protractor 4, you don't need to use the internal `caps_` property anymore, since those values will be exposed directly in the `getCapabilities()` result.